# Bootstrap, flex and hamburger menu on phones

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

just note at the start that I am NOT frontend developer, just backend.

I have layout like that: https://codeply.com/v/nZU6s0EkvE

First of all I am not sure wheter I should make it that way or maybe using grid. I just needed side menu and content to get 100% height. And flex was the only option that worked without showing scrollbars

Now, when I make the screen smaller there are two problems:

- content doesn't take 100% anymore
- side menu goes to the top - this actually is not a problem, somehow I wanted that.

Now the question - how can I solve the first problem?
And second question - what should I do to show hamburger menu on phones instead of this side menu (going up)?

Answer (score 1):

For your flex problems:
You're not [enabling the flex behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) at all until the small breakpoint with `.d-sm-flex`.
Use `.d-flex` to enable for all breakpoints.
You want to change the [flex direction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#direction) at the small breakpoint (start with column and go to row)

```html
            <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row h-100">
                <div class="bg-gray p-2">
                    Menu
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grow-1 bg-blue p-2">
                    Treść
                </div>
            </div>
```

As for using the "hamburger" button (technically a separate question) read-up on the `.navbar` [Responsive behaviors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors) and using the `.navbar-toggler` with [External content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#external-content). If you have problems implementing that, come back and post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to figure it out thanks to Arleigh Hix.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 h-100 bg-red">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <nav class="bg-gray p-1">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="main flex-grow-1 bg-purple">
            <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column h-100">
                <nav class="d-flex navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-gray">
                    <div class="">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="flex-grow-1 bg-blue p-2">
                    Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Notice that this vertical navbar does not have .navbar class. It's because .navbar class makes navbar content to be vertically centered. So only .d-flex (also present in .navbar class) is needed as far as I think.